# How forgiving is God?

Tags: gods

Does god forgive you if you genuinely feel sorry for something you have done? For instance, someone vowed to god that he or she won't do this or that to get something in life. But the person breaks it and does that specific thing, will God not give the person what he asked for because he broke the vow?

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/does-god-really-punish) question is somewhat different from what I have asked.

Comment: Well in order to be forgiving, he first needs to be angry (outside situations specific to personal matters in his lives). Do you have any reason to believe God gets angry for non-personal matters?